# How to have stopifnot() return an error when called on a missing (NULL) element of a list?

Tags: r, testing

With stopifnot(), how to test an element in a list, also checking that the element itself exists?

For example li is a list, which contains an item. I want to ensure that item is equal to 0.

```
li <- list()
li$item <- 1
stopifnot(li$item == 0)
# Error: l$x == 0 is not TRUE
```

Returned an error, which is what I want.
But if I make a typo and enter :

```
stopifnot(li$tem == 0)
```

R doesn't return an error. Even though this element doesn't exist in the list:

```
li$tem
# NULL
```

Why R doesn't tell me that the element 'tem' is not found in the list?

```
li$tem == 0
```

evaluates to logical(0).

Comment: For anyone interested in why `stopifnot()` does not give an error with a `logical(0)`, see: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-December/434610.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not so much the `stopifnot()` function, but rather the use of `==` for doing the comparison:

```r
# returns an empty logical vector, not TRUE or FALSE:
li$tem == 0 # logical(0)
# according to ?`==` we should use identical() instead of ==:
identical(li$tem, 0) # returns FALSE
# this now works as it should, i.e. it throws an error:
stopifnot(identical(li$tem, 0))
```

From `?"=="`:

> Do not use == and != for tests, such as in if expressions, where you must get a single TRUE or FALSE. Unless you are absolutely sure that nothing unusual can happen, you should use the identical function instead.

Comment: Thanks I have seen identical() but didn't bother using it. The issue now is that one number is an integer, the other one a numeric. I have to convert one number to integer so that I can compare the numbers.

Comment: That's true, indentical() also looks at the type of the vector so you could use isTRUE(all.equal(li$tem,0)) if you just want to check for "near equality" but I wouldn't advise this. Better to do identical(x, 0L) to check that x is an integer 0.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten that `L` at the end of a number declaration makes it an integer. Writing `0L` is much shorter than writing `as.integer(0)`.